# No permite borrar registros tabla SQL en Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Tengo una tabla de SQL Server vinculada en un aplicativo de Access. Si intento eliminar registros mediante una consulta de eliminación no hay problema. Pero si intento eliminar registros directamente en tabla o a través de una consulta de selección en modo hoja de datos no permite borrar los registros y me sale la siguiente advertencia:

> "El motor de base de datos Microsoft Access detuvo el proceso porque otro usuario está intentando modificar los datos al mismo tiempo."

Lo mismo sucede al actualizar los datos. No hay ningún otro usuario modificando los datos.

El problema es que aún existen muchos formularios *legacy* que usan modo hoja de datos para borrar registros en vez de usar consultas de actualización y, por ahora, es impensable modificar todos esos formularios.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué puede estar sucediendo?

Gracias!

**UPDATE FINAL:**
El problema era que el campo bit fue creado como nullable (NULL) cuando, he descubierto, que este tipo de dato no es convertible a Access. Es necesario, pues, establecerlo a NOT NULL y crear un default a 0 (o 1, según sea el caso).

Así que, en vez de esto:

`[FIELD] [bit] NULL`

Necesitamos esto:

`[FIELD] [bit] NOT NULL`

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [FIELD] GO`

UPDATE: Me he dado cuenta de que esto solo sucede con los registros nuevos añadidos desde Access, pero no con los registros originales de la tabla de SQL.

Comment: ¿Revisaste el [*tipo de bloqueo*](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/recordlocks-propiedad-6ca29bbb-8824-4671-8087-97fe0568019a)?

Comment: Sí, lo he comprobado. Sin bloqueo. También he probado bloqueo pesimista y nada.

Comment: Access no permite borrar registros en consultas de selección que combinen varias tablas /campos calculados. Si los campos son todos de la misma tabla, debería dejarte. De hecho, lo que más raro veo es que no puedas eliminar registro directamente en tabla. ¿Hay algún campo calculado o alguna columna de búsqueda que tire de macros/SQL o similar? Tiene pinta de que a lo mejor se te ha corrompido. ¿Probaste a reparar/compactar? ¿Alguna macro en segundo plano que pueda estar actuando?

Comment: @Esei Es una tabla simple, sin campos calculados ni búsquedas con macros ni nada. He probado a c&r y nada. Me pregunto si no será un problema de configuración de la instancia, porque si hago lo mismo con mi instancia local (con otra tabla) no da problemas...

Comment: Finalmente el error se debía a un campo bit nullable (que permita nulos). Se solucionó estableciendo el campo bit a NOT NULL y creando un default a 0. Gracias por vuestras respuestas!